# Editing Entries In-line In Admin Area

Tags: admin, custom

Has anyone made it possible to edit entries directly in the admin area (i.e. /admin/entries/{section}) without having to go into each individual entry?

I've built a voucher system that the users need to quickly be able to tick off a number of vouchers as i.e. a family comes in - not having to open five voucher entries and tick off one at a time.

[image]

Having a light switch field where this "Voucher Status" field is would be perfect.

If that's not possible, even adding a button that I could trigger an ajax action on would be fine - I'm just not sure how to go about that either. I haven't tried to customise the admin area of Craft before.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong about using the HUD?

Comment: Hi Robin. I don't quite follow - what do you mean (the HUD)? I'm hoping to get to a point where you could rapidly tick off half a dozen vouchers or even use the checkboxes and add another button up by the status change functionality. I'm just trying to avoid having to open entries, go back, search for an order again etc. Thanks.

Comment: HUD = head up display, the thing that opens when you create a new element inside the ElementSelectModal or when you double click on a selected ElementSelectField. It also pops up when you select an element in the BaseElementIndex and click on `edit entry`. There is a checkbox in each row, just check one (not more) and the ElementActionMenu will be shown. You can either use that `edit entry` button or create a custom ElementAction in order to change alle selected elements

Comment: Hi Robin. Oh I see - no that's still 5 clicks per entry. I'm after one. I'm just lacking the info to know if there are any plugins that do this or how to customise the entries listing without touching core code. Thanks though.